# Traveling from Bangkok thu Oman then Germany final destination Canada

Tags: visas, transit, germany, canadian-citizens, oman

I am Canadian citizen  I am leaving Bangkok, transit in Oman, transit in Frankfurt, and arriving final destination Canada. Do I need any transit visas for this itinerary?

Comment: Travel restrictions can change rapidly, checking Timatic should help you stay up-to-date https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true

Answer (score 2):

According to [Visa policy of Oman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Oman):

> Visitors from any country who hold onward tickets may transit through Oman without a visa for up to 6 hours if proceeding by the same flight.

If you do not meet this transit requirement (such as if your next flight is the next day, for example), then you will need to obtain an eVisa for Oman.

Canadian citizens can enter the Schengen area (which covers Germany) for up to 90 days without a visa, so transit is no problem there.

If you are planning this trip in the near term, you will also need to check country entry restrictions related to the Covid-19 pandemic. Some countries require that some or all persons who enter the country for any reason must self-isolate or quarantine for 14 days. The exact restrictions are changing quickly at this time. Enlisting the help of a travel agent could be a good idea.

At the current time, [Government of Canada travel advice for Oman](https://travel.gc.ca/destinations/oman) states:

> Omani authorities have suspended all commercial flights in and out of the country until further notice.

So hopefully you're planning this for some undetermined time in the future.

Comment: Wikipedia is out of date (and not generally a good source to reference). The TWOV time is now 24 hours, not 6 hours, according to Timatic.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Still, transit through Oman is impossible at this time no matter what the connection time is.

Comment: If OP is in transit in Germany between Oman and Canada, then they will need usually not need to enter into Germany/Schengen itself.